# How to return CFDataRef without memory leak?[ios]

Tags: ios, autorelease, cfdata

When I return a `CFDataRef` by

```
(CFDataRef)MyFunction{
    .....
    CFDataRef data = CFDataCreate(NULL, buf, bufLen);
    free(buf);
    return data;
}
```

There is a memory leak, how to make `CFDataRef` autorelease?
the method [data autorelease] doesn't exit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't autorelease Core Foundation objects.  (However, you can autorelease Core Foundation objects that support toll-free bridging such as CFDataRef; see @newacct's answer below.)

The Objective-C convention is to name your method such that it starts with the word `new` to indicate that the caller is responsible for releasing its return value.  For example:

```
+ (CFDataRef)newDataRef {
    return CFDataCreate(...);
}

CFDataRef myDataRef = [self newDataRef];
...
CFRelease(myDataRef);
```

If you conform to this naming convention, the Xcode static analyzer will correctly flag Core Foundation memory managment issues.

Comment: thanks ,I rename the MyFunciotn to newMyFunction,the warnings are gone!

Comment: Not true. You *can* autorelease Core Foundation objects. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Toll-FreeBridgin/Toll-FreeBridgin.html "Note from the example that the memory management functions and methods are also interchangeable—you can use CFRelease with a Cocoa object and release and autorelease with a Core Foundation object."

Comment: @newacct: That is only true for specific Core Foundation objects that support toll-free bridging. CFDataRef does support toll-free bridging, so in this particular case you are correct.

Answer (score 3):

> how to make CFDataRef autorelease? the method [data autorelease]
>   doesn't exit.

Simply cast it to an object pointer type in order to call `autorelease`:

```
-(CFDataRef)MyFunction{
    .....
    CFDataRef data = CFDataCreate(NULL, buf, bufLen);
    free(buf);
    return (CFDataRef)[(id)data autorelease];
}
```